# Knockout: how to pass data to with binding?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to pass data to the following model but since the model is being bound using the 'with' statement it seems to fire right on page load and errors saying 'Name' is not defined.

```
<div data-bind="with: aFunction()">
    <div data-bind="text: test"></div>
    <input data-bind="value: test, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></input>
</div>


var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    var data = {Name : "Mark"};

    self.aFunction = function (data){
        var self = this;
        self.test = ko.observable(data.Name);  
        return self;
    }

    self.aFunction(data);

};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Because you're binding to `aFunction()`, you're actually executing that function (when the bindings are applied on page load) and attempting to bind `with: [function result]`
2. I'm not sure you can bind `with` to a function result.  Usually this is done with a property of the current binding context (as @lazyberezovsky illustrates with the "name" property in his answer)

Answer (score 0):

When using the `with` binding, you have to remember that changes the binding context you are currently in.

Now your model, frankly speaking, has a very odd setup in that it behaves more like a observable factory, producing observables rather than containing an observable.

If we changed your model to a more traditional approach like so: (this example becomes easy to illustrate where you are going down the wrong path)

**Model:**

```
var viewModel = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.Test = ko.observable();

    self.load = function(data) {
        if (data) {
            self.Test({ name: ko.observable(data.name) });
        }   
    };
    self.load(data);
};

var data = { name: 'Matt' };
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(data));
```

**Html:**

```
<!-- Once inside this markup, the scope changes to the things contained 
inside of Test(). Therefore your aliasing needs to look like the following -->
<div data-bind="with: Test">
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    <input data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></input>
</div>
```

**JsFiddle:**

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aFycy/4/) to demonstrate this example

**Explanation:**

It's important to note the documentation on the with binding:

> The with binding creates a new binding context, so that descendant
>   elements are bound in the context of a specified object.
>
> ...
>   *The with binding will dynamically add or remove descendant elements depending on whether the associated value is null/undefined or not*

This italicized section explains why using a With binding as in my example wouldn't blow up with an error if the observable `Test()` were to be null or undefined; the framework handles this situation by dynamically removing all descendant elements. This is demonstrated in my jsfiddle.

Also notice that I gave the object inside a property a property named `name` so that I can explicitly bind to it. If you are using a with binding on a property itself, you get into some hacks for trying to bind to it as a property so you are best off just have explicit properties IMO.

Hopefully this is helpful